# Self running php script?

Tags: php

**Situation**:
My php/html page retrieves the contents of another page on a different domain every 5-10 minutes or so.  I use a JavaScript setInterval() and a jquery .load() to request content from the other domain into an element on my page. Each time it retrieves content, javascript compares new content with the previous content and then I make an Ajax call to a php script that sends me an email of what the changes are.

**Problem**:
It's all working fine and dandy except for the fact that I need a browser constantly open, requesting the updates.

**Question**:
Is there a way to accomplish this with some sort of 'self executing' script on the server? Something that I would only have to start once, and it continues to run on it's own without needing a browser to be open as long as I want the script to run?

Thanks in advance!
P.S. I'm not a php/javascript expert by any means, but I can get my way around.

Comment: If you have root access to your host (server or VPS) or cron permissions, you can use a cron job to run this every X minutes.

Comment: just use cron jobs on your server.. see this ~> http://www.nbill.co.uk/documentation/setting-up-a-cronjob.html

Comment: You can set a cron job to start your PHP script on the server.

Comment: php can be executed on the server quite easily via [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Javascript cannot.

Comment: Thank you, cron job was the answer.  I didn't know about these until now :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the thing you are looking for is a cron job.

Comment: "javascript compares new content with the previous content and then I make an Ajax call..." Can you elaborate on how this is accomplished via a cron job?

Comment: You don't. You just have to create one PHP file that does everything and then set a cron job to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

If your script relies on Javascript for proper execution, you will need to use a browser to accomplish your goals.

However, if you can alter your script to perform all of the functionality via PHP, perhaps using [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to request the necessary data, you can use a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job to execute the script at regular intervals.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running a script at an interval, I would recommend using a bash script instead that runs in the background.

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]
do
    php "script.php"
    sleep 300
done
```

Then you can run the script like `nohup bash.sh`. 300 seconds = 5 minutes.